# How do I make my time-series data continuous in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have occupancy data that is recorded every time someone enters the house (Note: Value == 1 means there is a person inside the house).

For example (Table A):

```
Time                 Value
2019-05-12-16:44:22  1
2019-05-12-16:44:49  1
2019-05-12-16:45:43  1
2019-05-12-16:49:19  1
2019-05-12-16:52:19  1
...
```

But I need to compare this data with continuous data, which looks something like (Table B):

```
Time                 Value
2019-05-12-16:44:00  5.05
2019-05-12-16:45:00  5.05
2019-05-12-16:46:00  5.05
2019-05-12-16:47:00  12.05
2019-05-12-16:48:00  12.05
...
```

so basically, I need to match the length of table A & B so that it looks like:

```
Time                 Value  Value
2019-05-12-16:44:00  5.05   1
2019-05-12-16:45:00  5.05   1
2019-05-12-16:46:00  5.05   1
2019-05-12-16:47:00  12.05  1
2019-05-12-16:48:00  12.05  1
...
```

My question is: How can I change Table A just like Table B so that data is continuous (in minutes) ?

Comment: can you please rephrase your question for more clarity

Comment: In addition to what @BhosaleShrikant, can you at least explain the operation to perform? Have you actually tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to truncate minutes and join the tables based on the new time index.